# how does commit/reveal solve front-running?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, attacks

I am trying to make sure I understand something correctly, so I will pose a problem with a solution.

**Problem:**

Let's say `commit` has been called. After this, we call the `reveal`. attacker listens to `commit` transactions, and calls the `commit` was a front-run by himself. Then, attacker listens to `reveal` transactions. What attacker does now is as soon as he figures out there's a new `reveal` transaction in the pool, he grabs the arguments(these are the arguments how the hash was derived from), hashes them and if it matches the one already stored on his own address when he called `commit` , then attacker will also front-run the `reveal` transaction.

**Solution:**

I think the only solution to the above problem is that we include `msg.sender` while getting the commitment hash. This way, even if attacker listens to `reveal` transactions, and front-runs it, it won't be enough, because `msg.sender` of attacker will be different and it won't produce the same hash as commitment.

Question 1: What do you think ? Am I right about Solution above ?

Question 2: I've seen some implementations that `msg.sender` is not included while deriving a commitment hash. This means that front-run still exists, which means attacker front-runs `commit` , and then front-runs `reveal`.  If there're lots of transactions happening, sure, this front-run doesn't make any sense to the attacker, but I don't think `commit-reveal` scheme solves front-run if we use it for `quiz` smart contract where user submits the solution and gets the reward, because attacker can listen to `commit` again and it's highly likely that whoever commits, is most likely the winner, so attacker will also wait for the `reveal` from the same user who called `commit` and front-runs again. What do you think about this ? For me, for quiz systems, `commit/reveal` doesn't seem a good solution to solve front-running. Could you put some examples where it would really be useful ? **NOTE:** I know `commit/reveal` is a good scheme, but I need examples where it solves the front-running problem and doesn't use `msg.sender` in the hash too.

Comment: As this question is old, [Project Shutter has now commit-and-reveal scheme going live as the part of Gnosis Chain block building](https://mevblocker.io/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some remarks:

- Usually commit and reveal phases are separated such that no commit message are allowed after certain point. That way if someone send a reveal message an attacker no longer can send a commit with the answer.
- The committed message must include something extra that an attacker cannot alter like msg.sender or something he cannot guess like a random nonce.

Commit+reveal is a technique that helps prevent some cases of front-running but it is not an efficient situation requiring two transactions and several blocks in between those transactions.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael, but I think my 2nd question in the actual question stays unanswered. Just to quickly explain the second question, imagine there's a contract about quiz and it rewards user that solved the quiz. If we use commit/reveal and don't include msg.sender in the hash(also not any kind of address), and then we have `msg.sender.transfer` somewhere in the `reveal`,  then we have the same front-run attack, because attacker front-runs `commit` transaciton and then front-runs `reveal` transaction and gets the reward, which seems very possible and wrong to me. what do you think ?

Comment: if someone is not very careful, it could be still beneficial for an attacker to front-run `commit` and then `reveal` transactions of the same user. I brought `quiz` example. Let's say the `commit` just uses hash of `secret + solution`.Nothing else. and in the reveal, after all the check, we do this `msg.sender.transfer`.What happens here is that attacker front-runs `commit` transaction, because whoever `commits` transaction, it's highly likely they solved the quiz. So attacker then also listens to the `reveal` transaction from the same user and front-runs `reveal` transaction. don't you agree?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili It is problematic if someone can front run your commit message.

Comment: I just brought an example of one scenario. Don't you agree with my example that it's possible in my scenario about `quiz` ?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili I'd try to avoid the possibility of someone front running a commit message. For example making impossible to commit the same message more than once.

Comment: Hm, Rob below mentioned that that is not as easy as it sounds and I wonder why. It pretty much looks easy to me to do this .

Comment: @NikaKurashvili If you do it wrong you may cause a DoS to valid users.

Comment: Any chance you might have time to reproduce it from this example  of yours ?  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73570/what-is-the-pre-commit-scheme-to-defeat-frontrunning-attack

Comment: @NikaKurashvili I think that example mostly works, but if instead it were `mapping(bytes32 => address ) commitments` mappings from commitment to msg.sender it will possible to DoS the commit message.

Comment: How can this cause `DoS` though ? `DoS` means no users will be allowed to call `commit` anymore (doesn't matter what the commitment is), but in this case, no users will be able to call `comit`  on the same `commitment` that has already been used, if they choose different `commitment`, they will still be able to call it . any ideas ?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili If the malicious party is listening pending transactions it can race and commit the hash, blocking a legitime user. The user can submit another commit but it will be spending more ether for transaction fees.

Comment: Yeah, but `DOS` will only be caused for the user that is submitting the same hash. I call `DOS` attack when it causes that no users at all can call the function successfully anymore. I guess, what you describe is not `DOS` and only applies to 1 user that is submitting the same hash. Right ?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili The same can be done for every user. Perhaps it has another name but the problem exists. A malicious party blocking users from the platform.

Comment: how can it be done from all user ? That's what I don't get.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili It can be done the same way any other front run. Listen for any transaction in the pending pool with the commit message and use more gas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120048/discussion-between-nika-kurashvili-and-ismael).

Answer (score 3):

> Question 1: What do you think ? Am I right about Solution above ?

Agree. To prevent front-running, use a factor like `msg.sender` in the hash function so the front-runner can know the secret and still be unable to use that knowledge.

For example, consider a piggy bank with a secret word that releases the money. If the withdraw function uses (pseudo) `hash(secret)` then the front-runner can learn the secret word and try to claim the money first. If the function uses `hash(msg.sender, secret)`, then front-running is prevented - the secret has to be sent from a certain address - two factors instead of one.

You should also consider how the contract executes the awarding of the prize. Consider  `msg.sender.transfer()` versus `rightPerson.transfer()`. You want to be sure that the *effect* is that only the correct account ever actually wins.

For certain apps, you might want to make it possible for anyone to pay gas to push funds to the right person. Suppose there is no reason for Alice to want to leave her funds in place and Bob wants to be a hero and pay her gas. That can work as long as the contract is certain about where the money should go.

```
mapping(bytes32 => unit) public pendingPayments;

function beAHero(address receiver, bytes32 secret) public {
  bytes32 key = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(receiver, secret));
  uint amount = pendingPayments[key];
  if(amount > 0) {
    pendingPayments[key] = 0;
    receiver.transfer(amount);
    // emit ...
  }
}
```

Alice could give Bob her secret and all Bob would be able to do is pay for gas, if he wants to. Alice gets the money in any case. If `receiver.transfer()` is instead `msg.sender.transfer()` then anyone who knows the secret can take Alice's money, including front-runners who listen to the pending transactions.

(just a scribble, so please forgive my typos).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great Answer, Rob. It really helps. What about my second question ?

Comment: TBH, I don't really understand the second question. I thought possibly my answer would help you look at those examples and work out if they're doing it right or doing it wrong. It's great to follow tail lights in a snow storm, but don't follow other cars into the ditch. ;-)

Comment: Just to quickly explain the second question,  imagine there's a contract about `quiz` and it rewards user that solved the quiz. If we use `commit/reveal` and don't include `msg.sender` in the hash, then we have the same front-run attack, because attacker front-runs `commit` transaciton and then `reveal` transaction and gets the reward, which seems very possible and wrong to me. what do you think ?

Comment: if someone is not very careful, it could be still beneficial for an attacker to front-run `commit` and then `reveal` transactions of the same user. I brought `quiz` example. Let's say the `commit` just uses hash of `secret + solution`.Nothing else. and in the reveal, after all the check, we do this `msg.sender.transfer`.What happens here is that attacker front-runs `commit` transaction, because whoever `commits` transaction, it's highly likely they solved the quiz. So attacker then also listens to the `reveal` transaction from the same user and front-runs `reveal` transaction. don't you agree?

Comment: Any transaction can potentially be front-run(ned) - includes the commit. Whether the honest sender would reveal when they can see their commit lost out to someone else depends on app details. One thing you should always do is prevent the re-use of a known hash - previously seen, so the victim would see that their transaction failed. If they walk away and never reveal then the attacker doesn't know how to finish. Still, things are greatly simplified by relying on the msg.sender signer in the hash function.

Comment: I would also add that it's common for developers to copy/paste code so this idea of never allowing a previously-observed hash to be used again is harder than it sounds. Can you think of another factor to include in the hash function so that hashes observed in one instance are useless in all other instances of the same code? ;-)

Comment: Got it! Though, I dont get why it is hard to not allow previously submitted/observed hash to be used again. Just simple mapping would do the trick, no ?

Answer (score 0):

If the malicious owner sees the hash you submitted and submits the same hash, your solution breaks down.

Commit-reveal can be used only if it is hidden when committing and open when revealing. When committing, there are so many people who have committed it, so it should be difficult to know who's right.

A suitable example of commit-reveal is to answer a quiz or bid.

Comment: Then, how does commit/reveal solve front-running attack in the first place ? because malicious owner can just listen to `commit` transactions and submit the same hashes. Then they can also listen to `reveal` transactions and submit the solutions again.

Comment: Because many people commit and don't know who's the right answer, there is no motivation for the attack. You just need to make it cost more than profit.

Comment: I think it depends on what we use commit/reveal for. If there's a quiz on the smart contract, and whoever submits the solution, gets some money, I don't think `commit/reveal` would help in this case. I can explain why. let's say we use `commit/reveal` for this case. if someone is submitting a solution via `commit`, it's highly likely that he solved the quiz.  so malicious listens to `commit` transactions, and then listens to `reveal` transactions and still wins in this case.  Don't you agree ?

Comment: Updated my answer !

Comment: Many people think that they have taken the quiz, but few people get it right. It is not economical for an attacker to submit the same answer each time he submits a quiz answer.