# Commit-Reveal contract still vulnerable to front running. How can it be improved?

Tags: solidity, transactions, pending-transactions, attacks, frontrunning

I'm writing a contract and I want to shield it from front-running as best as it can possible be done (obviously, fully preventing front running would be ideal). My implementation is very similar to the Raffle implementation from  @Ismael [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/73577) so I will be using that:

```
contract Raffle {

    mapping(address => bytes32) commitments;
    mapping(uint256 => address) reserved;

    event Reserved(uint256 value, address owner);
    event Committed(bytes32 hash);

    function commit(bytes32 hash) public {
        require(commitments[msg.sender] == bytes32(0), "Already committed");
        commitments[msg.sender] = hash;
        emit Committed(hash); // Added this event for similarity
    }

    function reveal(uint256 nonce, uint256 value) public {
        bytes32 d = digest(nonce, value, msg.sender);
        require(commitments[msg.sender] == d, "Invalid data");
        require(reserved[value] == address(0), "Already reserved");
        reserved[value] = msg.sender;
        emit Reserved(value, msg.sender);
    }

    function digest(uint256 nonce, uint256 value, address sender) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(nonce, value, sender));
    }
}
```

**This contract is vulnerable to the following front running scenario**:

1. Honest user makes a commit. Commit is a hash so there is nothing the
   attacker can do at this point.
2. Eventually honest user will make transaction to use the `reveal` method. At this point both the `value` and `nonce` are made public.
3. Before the honest user's transaction is picked from the mempool, the
   attacker get's the now revealed parameters `value` and `nonce`, sends a
   high gas transaction to make his commit.
4. In sequence frontruns the reveal transaction from honest user. (3 and 4 may even be done in the same block)

**What measures can I take to prevent/mitigate this behavior?**

- Just like in the contract above I need both `commit` and `reveal` methods to be permanently open for interactions (Meaning I can't separate the methods in commit phase and reveal phase, as it would be done in a sealed bid auction)

---

My current idea for mitigation is to register the `block.number` with the commit, and in the `reveal` method only reserve the value if an arbitrary number of blocks has been mined since the commit was made. *E.g: You made the commit on block 100, you need to wait to block 110 to call reval (otherwise the transaction is reverted). This gives a 10 blocks "advantage" to the honest user, as attacker will need to wait 10 blocks to try to frontrun.*

The cons:

- It doesn't solve the problem, the `reveal` transaction may stay X blocks (X being the arbitrary number of blocks to wait) on the mempool, due to clogged blockchain, low gas, or  other reasons. Long enough for the attacker to frontrun.
- If the honest user mistakenly calls the reveal function before the number of blocks is mined he will have a failed transaction and the parameters will be revealed, cutting his advantage short.
- Hard to determine a reasonable number of blocks.

Comment: Do you absolutely need msg.sender to form the digest?

Comment: Hi @Undead8, I think I can make it work without it, but I don't see how that would solve the issue.

Comment: Just a question: if msg.sender is included in the hash, how is it possible to do a front-run attack, even when the nonce & value become public, if the attacker can't sign a transaction with the 'honest user's address?

Comment: @SergiJuanati The attacker doesn't need to sign. He will make a `commit` transaction with the same `value` (`nonce` is irrelevant once revealed) and **his address**, followed by a `reveal` transaction. The point is that the attacker can frontrun the honest user's `reveal` transaction by making both the `commit` and `reveal` transactions before the honest `reveal` is processed.

Comment: Ohh I see. I share a proposal through a new answer!

Comment: Isn't that even the commit and reveal can be front running by the attacker, the `msg.sender` is making sure the attacker only can reveal the things he committed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also propose a solution based on the `block.number`, which is safer than using `block.timestamp`, but with a different approach. Rather than using it to secure a reservation after several blocks, I would use it as an **ordering criterion** in case that multiple users go for the same number.

When a user commits a hash, the current block number is captured in the commitment struct. Afterwards, when a user reveals his/her number, the reveal function will determine if the number was:

a) **Free** => it will be assigned to the current user

b) **Not free** => it will compare the block numbers between the current user and the previously assigned user, and will update to the user with the oldest block (the first user that committed that number)

The updated code would look like this one:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract Raffle {
    struct Commitments {
        bytes32 commitment;
        uint256 blockNumber;
    }

    mapping(address => Commitments) commitments;
    mapping(uint256 => address) reserved;

    function commit(bytes32 hash) external {
        require(commitments[msg.sender].commitment == bytes32(0), "Already committed");
        commitments[msg.sender] = Commitments(hash, block.number);
    }

    function reveal(uint256 nonce, uint256 value) external {
        bytes32 d = digest(nonce, value, msg.sender);
        require(commitments[msg.sender].commitment == d, "Invalid data");
        if (reserved[value] == address(0)) {
            reserved[value] = msg.sender;
        } else if (commitments[reserved[value]].blockNumber > commitments[msg.sender].blockNumber) {
            reserved[value] = msg.sender;
        } else {
            revert('Already reserved');
        }
    }

    function digest(uint256 nonce, uint256 value, address sender) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(nonce, value, sender));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it provides a feasible approach for the sample code in the question. Unfortunally, this won't work for my particular case, since the `reveal` would be the last iteraction with the contract, and replacing the `reserved` value would be 'too late'. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If that is the case, then it's hard to solve the problem because an attacker will always be able to launch a higher-gas tx to do the reservation before. If security is a must for your contract, perhaps you need to refactor it to turn the commit-reveal into a phased process..

Answer (score 1):

Update the commit function such that a particular hash can only be submitted/accepted once.

```
  mapping(bytes32 => bool) committedHash;

  function commit(bytes32 hash) public {
    require(commitments[msg.sender] == bytes32(0), "Already committed");
    require(committedHash[hash] == false, "this hash is already used");
    committedHash[hash] = true;
    commitments[msg.sender] = hash;
    emit Committed(hash); // Added this event for similarity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue. I added comments on the lines that I changed so you can spot them easily.

Let me know if it works for your use case!

```
contract Raffle {

    mapping(address => bytes32) commitments;
    mapping(uint256 => address) reserved;
    mapping(bytes32 => address) commitOwners; // ADD THIS

    event Reserved(uint256 value, address owner);
    event Committed(bytes32 hash);

    function commit(bytes32 hash) public {
        require(commitments[msg.sender] == bytes32(0), "Already committed");
        require(commitOwners[hash] == address(0), "I HATE YOU FRONT RUNNER!"); // THIS MAKES IT IMPOSSIBLE TO COMMIT A NONCE/VALUE HASH THAT WAS ALREADY COMMITTED
        commitments[msg.sender] = hash;
        commitOwners[hash] = msg.sender;
        emit Committed(hash);
    }

    function reveal(uint256 nonce, uint256 value) public {
        bytes32 d = digest(nonce, value); // REMOVE MSG.SENDER
        require(commitments[msg.sender] == d, "Invalid data");
        require(reserved[value] == address(0), "Already reserved");
        reserved[value] = msg.sender;
        emit Reserved(value, msg.sender);
    }

    // REMOVE SENDER IN THIS FUNCTION
    function digest(uint256 nonce, uint256 value) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(nonce, value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Undead8, thanks for the answer. **The proposed solution wouldn't work though.** The `nonce` param is meant only to be used as a salt, making the hash impossible to guess. Once `nonce` and `value` are revealed in the mempool (event 2 in post) the attacker can get the `value`, use another random `nonce` and make a valid commit followed by a `reveal` operation with higher gas fees and frontrun the honest user. That solution also opens another possibility, will write it on the next comment.

Comment: In your solution, the commit also becomes unique, so all the attacker have to do is watch the mempool for the hash, and frontrun the `commit` transaction, using the same `hash` value, effectivelly blocking the honest user transaction.

Comment: Ok. It's not clear to me what is the front running issue here. Everyone can commit the hash of a value, so how does the front-runner knows that a particular value has... value? When is it known that a value is actually worth something and is worth front-running?

Comment: Well, in the `Raffle` contract presented there is no value to frontrun, but if you consider the `reveal` method to grant you an ether transfer, reserve a unique/rare token, or to represent a bid auction on an item, then you may have an incentive to do it. **The point here is that with a commit-reveal scheme you can still be frontrun** because once the `reveal` is called an attacker can frontrun both `commit` and `reveal` before the honest user `reveal` transaction is processed. The only way to block it (so far) is to have separated commit and reveal phases. Which I don't want to do in my case.

Comment: Hence why I'm looking for alternative methods to block it or mitigate front run in this situation. So far the block number is the only alternative I could come up with, and it's kind of fragile. That said, I really appreciate your help so far! :)